# Mysql decimal 65,6 not working

Tags: mysql, sql, decimal

In https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html documentation is informed that the Mysql 5.6 range up to 65 digits but I get the following warning:

"Out of range value for column"

decimal tried the following "183165897779341499863162899012758412346631957386569476513089.920000"

Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Out of range value for column

Could anyone help?

**EDIT:**

Even Mysql (M, D) allowing up to M = 65 and  D = 30 in practice to configure 65.6 M = maximum 59 range.

Answer (score 2):

Those are 66 digits, aren't they ?
http://www.lettercount.com/ (Result : 67 including the point)

Comment: The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.6 are as follows:

M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65. (Older versions of MySQL permitted a range of 1 to 254.)

D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

Comment: Only "183165897779341499863162899012758412346631957386569476513089" already generates the alert "Out of range value for column."

Comment: Yeah for sure ! as your "don'tknowwhatisthatnumber" is already a 66 and not 65 !

Comment: @ChaibiAlaa not really, in the last example there are only 60. It's the same number as in the original post, but without decimal digits. Therefore I wouldn't expect it to be out of range.